# Recommended way to replace several values in a tensor at once?

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, vectorization, tensor

Is there a batch way to replace several particular values in a pytorch tensor at once without a for loop?

Example:

```
old_values = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2])
old_new_value = [[2,22], [3,33], [6, 66]]
```

`old_new_value = [[2,22], [3,33], [6, 66]]`, which means 2 should be replaced by 22, and 3 should be replaced by 33 and 6 to 66

Can I have an efficient way to achieve the following end_result?

```
end_result = torch.Tensor([1, 22, 33, 4, 5, 5, 22, 33, 33, 22])
```

Note that old_values is not unique. Also, it is possible that old_new_value has a pair here(6, 66) that does not exist in the old_values.
Also, the `old_new_values` includes unique rows,

Comment: So, is it also the case that you'll have values in `old_new_val` e.g. `[6, 66]`  that are not in `old_values`? there's no `6` in your input tensor.

Comment: @kmario23: yes, `old_values` may or may not have all the values in `old_new_val`.

Comment: That's a *lot* of flexibility to ask for, particularly with tensor compute frameworks such as PyTorch. I'm not aware of any straightforward way to handle all of your cases, without some `for` loop thrown in for massaging the arrays in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any duplicate elements in your input tensor, here's one straightforward way using *masking* and value assignment using *basic indexing*. (I'll assume that the data type of the input tensor is `int`. But, you can simply adapt this code in a straightforward manner to other `dtype`s). Below is a reproducible illustration, with explanations interspersed in inline comments.

```
# input tensors to work with
In [75]: old_values    
Out[75]: tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=torch.int32)

In [77]: old_new_value      
Out[77]:
tensor([[ 2, 22],
        [ 3, 33]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

---

```
# generate a boolean mask using the values that need to be replaced (i.e. 2 & 3)
In [78]: boolean_mask = (old_values == old_new_value[:, :1]).sum(dim=0).bool() 

In [79]: boolean_mask 
Out[79]: tensor([False,  True,  True, False, False])

# assign the new values by basic indexing
In [80]: old_values[boolean_mask] = old_new_value[:, 1:].squeeze() 

# sanity check!
In [81]: old_values 
Out[81]: tensor([ 1, 22, 33,  4,  5], dtype=torch.int32)
```

**A small note on efficiency**: Throughout the whole process, we never made any copy of the data (i.e. we operate only on new *views* by massaging the shapes according to our needs). Therefore, the runtime would be blazing fast.

Comment: It is not quite right. Imagine the following: ```old_new_value=torch.tensor([[2, 1], [5, 1]])```. and ```old_values = tensor([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2])```

Comment: You're right. The above approach applies only to input tensors without duplicate values. Please update your question with this info.

Comment: As suggested, I edited the question to include the corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure anyone still cares about this, but just in case, here is a solution that also works when `old_values` is not unique:

```
mask = old_values == old_new_value[:, :1]
new_values = (1 - mask.sum(dim=0)) * old_values + (mask * old_new_value[:,1:]).sum(dim=0)
```

Masking works as in @kmario23's solution, but the mask is multiplied with the new values and sum-reduced to end up with the new values at all the right replacement positions. The negative mask is applied to the old values to use those at all other positions. Then both masked tensors are summed to obtain the desired result.